# Python scraping - subtract class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am new to python and programming and scraping.
I would like to subtract one html tag from another:
in "game_elements" there are all matches including lives, in "game_elements_live" there are only lives. In your opinion is it possible to only have non-live matches?
I use requests and BeautifulSoup
thank you so much

```
game_elements = html.select(".cardEvent.prebootFreeze.ng-star-inserted")
game_elements_live = html.select(".cardEvent.prebootFreeze.ng-star-inserted.is-live")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using version 4.7.0 or later of Beautiful Soup, the `select` method should support [the `:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), in which case `game_elements = html.select(".cardEvent.prebootFreeze.ng-star-inserted:not(.is-live)")` should work

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the ": not" works fine

Answer (score -1):

`class_elements=".cardEvent.prebootFreeze.ng-star-inserted" game_elements_live = html.select(class_elements) for i in range(0,8): class_elements.pop() game_elements=html.select(class_elements)`

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the ": not" works fine

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 